# Nullable Object must have a value #2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to reuse the same code I've always used but now it is encountering an error.

I'm looping through various user tables, and in there I do this:

```
DateTime dcdt = (DateTime)u.DateCreated;
DateTime lldt = (DateTime)u.LastLogon;
userRow["DateCreated"] = dcdt.ToShortDateString();
```

inside the loop. I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

**The error highlights "lldt" line**, instead of "dcdt" which comes first. That is strange in and of itself. Both these fields in the database "allow nulls" is checked. And they both could be null or neither might be null.

The two values are both listed as DateTime? types through intellisense.

I don't understand why ASP.NET refuses to allow me to output blank for null dates. If it is empty/null, then logic would suggest that ASP.NET should just print nothing.

How else am I suppose to output null dates? I tried adding if statements to prevent trying to cast null DateTimes, but it doesn't help, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've said, the data type of `u.LastLogon` is `DateTime?`. This means that it may or may not have a value. By casting to `DateTime`, you are requiring it to have a value. In this case, it does not.

Depending on what you're trying to do with it, you may want to check the `HasValue` property:

```
userRow["LastLogon"] = u.LastLogin.HasValue ? 
                       (object) u.LastLogin.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value;
```

---

If your database `LastLogon` column is of DateTime type, then you should be able to do:

```
userRow["LastLogon"] = u.LastLogin.HasValue ? 
                       (object) u.LastLogin.Value : DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: So what do I do about it? Do I not cast? Do I continue to use the  ShortDateString() on the DateTime? instead of DateTime  ?

Comment: Exactly how does `u.LastLogon.Value.ToShortDateString()` not work?

Comment: Apparently it wasn't working because of the DBNull.Value line. Since userRow["LastLogon"] is suppose to be string. Replacing it with String.Empty works. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: userRow["LastLogon"] = u.LastLogon.HasValue ? u.LastLogon.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty    <--- this works; Thanks a lot!

Comment: Edited: you need to cast to `object` first. You should confirm that this works in the database. `String.Empty` is not the same thing as `NULL` in database terms. What is the type of the column?

Comment: String is the type of the column of userRow["LastLogon"]. u.LastLogon.Value.ToShortDateString() it works, do I really need to cast as object?

Comment: I meant the type of the column in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to call a method (`dcdt.ToShortDateString()`) on a DateTime? which doesn't have a value (it is, indeed, null).  Try this:

```
dcdt.HasValue ? dcdt.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty;
```

EDIT (Just re-read the question): Also, don't try to convert to DateTime.  Preserve the nullable.

EDIT #2 (based on comments):

Try this:

```
if (dcdt.HasValue) 
{ userRow["DateCreated"] = dcdt.ToShortDateString(); } 
else
{ userRow = DbNull.Value }
```

Comment: u.LastLogon.HasValue ? u.LastLogon.Value.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value;    or u.LastLogon.HasValue ? u.LastLogon.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value;    refuses to work. It won't compile like that.    LastLogon is a type of DateTime?.

Comment: Thats because DBNull.Value is not a string- the expression must return a consistent data type.  I'll edit appropriately

Comment: I think I solved it. I used this: userRow["LastLogon"] = u.LastLogon.HasValue ? u.LastLogon.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty;

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like the following in your data access code:

```
DataTable  dt       = ExecuteSomeQuery() ;
object     value    = dt.Rows[0]["nullable_datetime_column"] ;
DateTime?  instance = value != null && value is DateTime ? (DateTime?)value : (DateTime?)null ) ;
```

If the column returned is NULL, it will be returned as a System.DBNull, otherwise it will be returned as an instance of DateTime (or whatever the appropriate mapped type is — int, string, etc). Consequently, you need to check the type of object returned from the query before trying to cast it.

Comment: It's already DateTime? type. Now I want to convert it to a String using ShortDateTimeString function in DateTime class. It won't let me.

Comment: In that case, `string s = instance.HasValue ? instance.Value.ToString() : "" ;` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But someone else kinda beat you to the answer in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that Dexter asked how he should go about it. Well, I would create an extension.

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(this DateTime? dateTime, string format)
    {
        return dateTime.HasValue ? dateTime.Value.ToString(format) : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
DateTime? dt2 = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd-MM-yy"));
Console.WriteLine(dt2.ToString("dd-MM-yy"));
```

Note that I can call extension method on a nullable type if the object is null.

Comment: this is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is .NET `null` is not the same as SQL NULL. SQL Null is [System.DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). So it is a [non-`null`] value in .NET.

Comment: So how do I make it so that it should either print nothing or print a date if available?

Comment: Technically Frazell is correct, but I'm pretty sure the translation happens automatically. If your datetime column is null, you will see a .net null. But that's not the problem, You have to write some code to check if it's null and print nothing. As you've seen, the most compact way to do this is with ?. ASP.NET won't do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

```
DateTime? dateTime = u.LastLogon?.ToShortDateString()
```